# Where can I find a standalone installer for Windows 7 Service Pack 1?

Tags: windows-7, download, service-pack

I've searched everywhere and can't find a standalone MSI or EXE for Windows 7 Service Pack 1.

Does it exist somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5842

For 64-bit Windows 7, download the file "windows6.1-KB976932-X64.exe"

For 32-bit Windows 7, download the file "windows6.1-KB976932-X86.exe"

Comment: For some reason, MS liked to refer to their standalone networkless install option as network installs, or labels them as for network administrators for some reason. Looks like they dropped that slightly confusing nonmenclature

Comment: you know, I saw that page and dismissed it.  I should have looked closer.